# Python Module for Non-canonical Keyboard Input Processing

Tags: python, keyboard-events

I have a Python-3 application that has an interactive command-line interface. Now I would like to add non-canonical keyboard input functionality to this application. I would like it to behave much like how Python interpreter handles its keyboard inputs - for example, keys like up-arrow and down-arrow could scroll command histories and other control keys could move the cursor to beginning/end of line, etc.

I had a cursory glance of *getkey* and *keyboard* modules, but what is the best (and easiest) Python 3 module that I could use for this feature?

Comment: there are special modules for command line - even IPython use one of them - [Python Prompt Toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit). Even standard module [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) should have some of this functions. Most of them use modul `readline` for this.

Answer (score 2):

There are special modules to create `interactive command line`.

They can use special keys to show history, edit line, auto suggestions.

There is standard module [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) which should have this functionality.

See also extended [cmd2](https://github.com/python-cmd2/cmd2)

Probably the most popular is [Python Prompt Toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit). Probably even `IPython` uses it.

See [Gallery](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/gallery.html#ptpython-a-python-repl), [basic tutorila](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/tutorials/repl.html) and [examples with PtPython](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython/)

[image]

Probably most of them use standard modul [readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) - so maybe you will need this for your project.

---

Other

- [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/prompts/) - probably it can also works as interactive command prompt
- [bullet](https://github.com/Mckinsey666/bullet) - it has interesting menus
- [qprompt](https://pypi.org/project/qprompt/)
- [prompter](https://github.com/tylerdave/prompter)
- [promplty](https://github.com/aventurella/promptly)
- [python-prompt](https://github.com/sfischer13/python-prompt)

---

BTW: [4 Python libraries for building great command-line user interfaces](https://opensource.com/article/17/5/4-practical-python-libraries)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking the time to respond. I am using python-prompt for my needs and it works great! Thanks!